# Pairing list elements with indexes

Tags: f#

Given a list of elements, I need to turn each element into a pair of the index number and the element. There are several ways to do it; this is the most concise I have found so far:

```
List.mapi (fun i x->i,x) xs
```

But is there a more concise/idiomatic way to do it? For example, does F# have some built-in function to turn two elements into a pair, some equivalent of the C++ `make_pair`?

Comment: The coma is pairing, as you already use it with `(x,y)`. Pairing two lists is basically `List.zip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function in the standard library that does exactly that: [`List.indexed`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#indexed)

Answer (score 1):

## Eight Ways to Write Indexed

As there is more than one way to do it (TIMTOWTDI) it is always good to learn about different approaches and it different pros and cons. Remember that there is never only one way to solve something. Here some examples you can learn from if you try to understand them.

### 1. The List Comprehension

```
let indexed1 xs =
    let mutable idx = 0
    [ for x in xs do
        yield idx,x
        idx <- idx + 1 ]
```

### 2. Ziping It!

```
let indexed2 xs =
    List.zip
        (List.init (List.length xs) id)
         xs
```

### 3. Recursion

```
let indexed3 xs =
    let rec cata idx xs =
        match xs with
        | []    -> []
        | x::xs -> (idx,x) :: cata (idx+1) xs
    cata 0 xs
```

### 4. Tail-Recursion

```
let indexed4 xs =
    let rec loop idx result xs =
        match xs with
        | []    -> result
        | x::xs -> loop (idx+1) ((idx,x) :: result) xs
    List.rev (loop 0 [] xs)
```

### 5. Folding it

```
let indexed5 xs =
    let mutable idx = -1
    List.fold (fun state x ->
        idx <- idx + 1
        (idx,x) :: state
    ) [] xs
    |> List.rev
```

### 6. Folding without mutable

```
let indexed6 xs =
    List.fold (fun (idx,state) x ->
        (idx+1), (idx,x) :: state
    ) (0,[]) xs
    |> snd
    |> List.rev
```

### 7. Folding it Backwards

```
let indexed7 xs =
    let lastIdx = List.length xs - 1
    List.foldBack (fun x (idx,xs) ->
        (idx-1), ((idx,x) :: xs)
    ) xs (lastIdx,[])
    |> snd
```

### 8. Arraying it

```
let indexed8 xs =
    let arr = Array.ofList xs
    let mutable result = []
    for idx=(arr.Length - 1) downto 0 do
        result <- (idx,arr.[idx]) :: result
    result
```